# How do I display grouped ID's as a list with their respective values?

Tags: sql, joomla, phpmyadmin, virtuemart

How do I not get all the ID's grouped, but instead listed from first to last; with all their respective values in the columns next to them?

Instead of grouping it, it should show ID 1 and its value, ID 2 and its value. EVEN if the values for the ID is the same. I tried removing the `GROUP_CONCAT`, but then it's only showing one ID per customfield_value?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(virtuemart_product_id), customfield_value, COUNT(*) c
FROM jos_virtuemart_product_customfields
WHERE virtuemart_custom_id = 6
GROUP BY customfield_value
HAVING c > 1
```

It's working currently, but grouping the ID's and spacing them with a comma. Should just display as in a normal table/list format.

Currently it shows like this(as you can see, it's ALL the same ICOS number, but different ID's. I ONLY need to display the values WHERE the ICOS NUMBER is "duplicate"):

```
   ID    ICOS  Count
1,2,3  775896      3
```

It should be displaying like this:

```
   ID    ICOS  Count
    1  775896      1
    2  775896      1
    3  775896      1
```

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Maybe add `virtuemart_product_id` to GROUP BY  instead of GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: I will edit to show how it's currently showing

Comment: What's your DBMS, looks like MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rows where the `customfield_value` is not unique:

```
-- Assuming MySQL
SELECT virtuemart_product_id, customfield_value
   , COUNT(*) c -- maybe not needed
FROM jos_virtuemart_product_customfields
WHERE virtuemart_custom_id = 6
  AND customfield_value IN
 ( SELECT customfield_value
   FROM jos_virtuemart_product_customfields
   WHERE virtuemart_custom_id = 6
   GROUP BY customfield_value
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- more than one row exists
 ) 
GROUP BY virtuemart_product_id, customfield_value -- maybe not needed
```

If the `virtuemart_product_id` is unique you don't need the outer count/group by as it will always be 1.

Comment: WOW thanks a lot  this is working! Yes that is PRECISELY what I needed! Thank you so much! Really great answer. I can now see the logic behind it. I'm quite new to phpmyadmin/mySQL so it's a learning curve.